# How to populate JSON data to select Box

Tags: ajax, node.js, mongodb

Well I am developing a site in nodejs and mongodb I want to populate json data into select box.Actually I am new in this technology so please guide me

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
<select id="my_sel"></select>
<script>
var opts = [
    {"name":"Test 1","code":"test-1"},
    {"name":"Test 2","code":"test-2"}
]
$.each(resp, function(k, v) {
    $('<option>').val(v.code).text(v.name).appendTo('#my_sel');
});
</script>
```